# can you make the output that appears in the console be automatically copied to your clipboard

Tags: c#

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();

for (int a = 1; a <= 100; a++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(input);
}
```

and then I want the input to be copied to the *clipboard* - all `100` words.

Comment: `ClipBoard.SetText(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(i => input)));`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest building the `output` which then assign *both* to `Clipboard` and `Console`:

```
using System.Linq;
// Note that Clipboard is Windows feature
using System.Windows.Forms;

...

string input = Console.ReadLine();

// repeat input 100 times
string output = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable
  .Range(1, 100)
  .Select(a => input));

Console.WriteLine(output);
Clipboard.SetText(output);
...
```

Comment: `Enumerable.Repeat(input, 100)` ;)